# Removing previously stored iCloud backup

Tags: ios, ios8, app-store, icloud, appstore-approval

My app got rejected due to **IOS storage guidelines** where it stated that my app was storing non user data in iCloud.

So now I have excluded the my files to get backup in iCloud.

Now when I run new build(which doesn't backup the data to iCloud) and verified that there are no new files are getting added. But when i update my old build (which backup the data in iCloud) to new build I still see the data in iCloud which is uploaded by old build. Although new build doesn't upload any data to iCloud.

My Question can I remove the old backup as my app now doesn't support iCloud backup.

Comment: @AliMajeed have you got any solution ?

Comment: i am creating icloud backup to test my app :(